# IIS 7.5 URL rewrite redirect rule for old URL to new URL

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I am trying to map this old webform URL

```
http://www.mysite.com/Listing.aspx?mlsnum=T5017910
```

to this new MVC URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/listing?id=T5017910
```

Somehow I cannot get it to work. My rule is as follows:

```
<rule name="My Listing Redirect Rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Listing.aspx?mlsnum=([0-9a-z]+)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="listing?id={R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<match url=...>` need to escape the `?` character try this instead:

```
<match url="Listing.aspx\?mlsnum=([0-9a-z]+)" ignoreCase="true"/>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I am still not able to get it to work.